# CSS/Bootstrap Place a set of buttons on top (and within) another div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to place these buttons alongside the icon button on top of the three images above them. I have tried setting them to position: absolute; and and using the z-index but this results in the buttons not aligning on top of each respective image, and if I do manually position them, they are no longer aligned whenever I resize the window. I want to keep these buttons trapped within the div that the images are in, while still overlaying them. Is this possible?[The image is shown below of what it currently looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kg3c.jpg)

here is the code:

```
<div class="imageSection">
<div class="container paddingContainer">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 borderEraser">
      <img class="imageResize" src="{% static 'webapp/images/srblogthumb.jpg' %}">
      <div class="info">
        <a class="btn btn-dark alignLeft" href="https://sebastianrichardsblog.herokuapp.com/home">View Project</a>
        <a class="btn btn-dark alignRight" href="#">View Code</a>
        <a href="#">
          <img class="iconImage" id="info1" src="{% static 'webapp/images/infoIcon.png' %}">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 borderEraser">
        <img class="imageResize" src="{% static 'webapp/images/digitaltwinthumb.jpg' %}">
        <div class="info">
          <a class="btn btn-dark alignLeft" href="https://sebastianrichardsblog.herokuapp.com/home">View Project</a>
          <a class="btn btn-dark alignRight" href="#">View Code</a>
          <a href="#">
            <img class="iconImage" id="info2" src="{% static 'webapp/images/infoIcon.png' %}">
          </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 borderEraser">
      <img class="imageResize" src="{% static 'webapp/images/mariopicthumb.jpg' %}">
      <div class="info">
        <a class="btn btn-dark alignLeft" href="https://sebastianrichardsblog.herokuapp.com/home">View Project</a>
        <a class="btn btn-dark alignRight" href="#">View Code</a>
        <a href="#">
          <img class="iconImage" id="info3" src="{% static 'webapp/images/infoIcon.png' %}">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and the css:

```
body {
    background-image: url("images/background2.jpeg");
}

h1 {
    color:aliceblue;
}

.srlogoimage {
    width: 75%;
    height: 75%

}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

.textCentered {
    text-align: center;
}

.imageResize {
    position: relative;
    width: 98%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-size: cover;
    border-radius: 10%;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    
    
}

.borderEraser {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
}


.alignRight {
    float: right;
    justify-content: center;
}

.alignLeft {
    float: left;
    justify-content: center;
}

.alignBottom {
    text-align: center;
}



.imageSection {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}



.info {
    padding: 1%;
    z-index: 9;
}
.iconImage {
    max-height: 10%;
    max-width: 10%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    
   
    

}

.paddingContainer {
    border-color: blanchedalmond;
    border: 50%;
    padding-left: 9%;
    padding-right: 9%;
    
}
```

any help or pointers will be greatly appreciated, I've been stuck on this for a week now

Comment: Have you considered placing the image as a background instead of an <img> in .borderEraser element?

And what css-styles did you try when placing the buttons with absolute over the image? I think this should work without misaligning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's something like this you trying to achieve:
[image]

You can add

```css
.borderEraser {
    position: relative;
}
.info {
    position:absolute;
    top: 50%; 
    left: 0; 
    right: 0; 
    transform: translate(0, 30%); // try different values
}
```

to your css-classes. To change positioning when images get small (on resize), you could maybe use media-queries and change position-style.

If you decide to use the images as backgrounds instead, you should use flexbox and align buttons accordingly.

Comment: It works, thanks a lot! the buttons are contained in the div. I'll definitely remember the top attribute